# Automate this code for many similar excel files and output to one file

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter as wr

rf = pd.read_excel('M07241.xlsx', skiprows=5)
rf = rf[['Name.2', 'Time.1']]
rf = rf.rename(columns = {'Name.2': 'participant', 'Time.1': 'reaction time'}, inplace = False)

part1=rf[rf['participant'].str.contains("PART 1")]['reaction time'].mean()
part2=rf[rf['participant'].str.contains("PART 2")]['reaction time'].mean()
part3=rf[rf['participant'].str.contains("PART 3")]['reaction time'].mean()

outWorkbook = wr.Workbook("maniout.xlsx")
outSheet = outWorkbook.add_worksheet()

part1mean = [part1]
part2mean = [part2]
part3mean = [part3]
outSheet.write("A1", "ps-part1")
outSheet.write("B1", "ps-part2")
outSheet.write("C1", "ps-part3")
outSheet.write(1, 0, part1mean[0])
outSheet.write(1, 1, part2mean[0])
outSheet.write(1, 2, part3mean[0])
outWorkbook.close()
```

The code reads and separates *'Part 1'*, *'Part 2'*, *'Part 3'* from the first column, **participant** and outputs the average of each *'Part'*, for corresponding values in the second column **reaction time**, to another file("maniout.xlsx") under 3 columns named "ps-part1", "ps-part2", "ps-part3". I need to automate this for many similar files and have their result *added/appended* to *"maniout.xlsx"* under "ps-part1", "ps-part2", "ps-part3". Many Thanks[image: to append the other files here]

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Sorry if this isn't clear. Just need to know how to apply this on multiple similar files in a folder and output the result of all to one file as illustrated. This code only reads one file as can be seen. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your all input files are in a single folder and all having the same type of data format( 2 columns with name as 'Name.2', 'Time.1')

So, in this case, we will loop through all the file and find mean of each data as per your code and add to list after finding all mean will write it xlsx file via pandas dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd

mean_data = []

for root, _, files in os.walk("Folder path"): <-- update folder path
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
            rf = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(root, file), skiprows=5)
            rf = rf[['Name.2', 'Time.1']]
            rf = rf.rename(columns={'Name.2': 'participant', 'Time.1': 'reaction time'}, inplace=False)

            part1 = rf[rf['participant'].str.contains("PART 1")]['reaction time'].mean()
            part2 = rf[rf['participant'].str.contains("PART 2")]['reaction time'].mean()
            part3 = rf[rf['participant'].str.contains("PART 3")]['reaction time'].mean()

            mean_data.append([part1, part2, part3])

df = pd.DataFrame(mean_data, columns=['ps-part1', 'ps-part2', 'ps-part3'])
df.to_excel("folder path with output.xlsx", index=False) <-- update output file path
```

Comment: Thank you @DevenRamani. That indeed solved my issue.